# Match besides first word and words starting with one or two hyphens

Tags: regex

I want to match any word **except**

- the first word
- anything that matches `(-(-)?\w*(=\w*)?)`

Example input:

> `test --par2 --par23=whatever 0 xd true hello "string test"`
>   `test --par23=whatever 0 xd true hello --par2 "string test"`
>   `test 0 xd "string test" true hello --par2 --par23=whatever`

What I want is:

```
0, xd, true, hello, "string test"
```

I don't want: `test`, `--par2` and `--par23=whatever`
Language: JavaScript

What would be a good idea?

Comment: Please include sample strings and expected results to your question

Comment: It would be a good idea to clarify what you mean with sample input and expected output.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot it. Now I did

Comment: @NilsBergmann Please check if my edit of your question is ok. And please specify what regex flavor/language you're using.

Comment: @bobble bubble your edit is perfect. thx

Comment: Before I went too far down this road, I'd look to see if there are existing JavaScript libraries that parse command line options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [The Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html). How about matching what you don't need but [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) what you need.

**don't want**

- `^\S+` [one or more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx) *non whitespaces* at [start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`\S` is negation of [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`)
- `\W-\S+` strings like `-foo`, `--bar` but want `bar-baz` (`\W` for *non word character*)

**but `(` capture `)`**

- `"[^"]+"` any quoted stuff (using [negated class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated))
- `\S+` one or more remaining *non whitespaces*

Order according matching priority and combine with pipes `|`

```
("[^"]+")|^\S+|\W-\S+|(\S+)
```

[See demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/tFAq8i/1). Grab captures of the two groups [like in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pw7krcj9/5/).

> [ "0", "xd", "true", "hello", ""string test"" ]

If using PCRE you can [skip the unneeded stuff](https://www.regex101.com/r/tFAq8i/2) by use of verbs [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex).

Comment: It works. But if you would add `-t` or something like that i would also captured. The problem is, i don't understand how it works :D

Comment: @NilsBergmann did [another update](https://jsfiddle.net/pw7krcj9/5/) for matching [`"quoted str"` if at start](https://www.regex101.com/r/nTpeDL/1). Using two capturing groups. Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right, do you mean this?

```
=\S* ([^=]*)
```

read the matched text in group1.

Comment: Not really. It simply match everything after ...--par23. But the string could also be `test 0 xd true hello "string test" --par2 --par23=whatever` or `test 0 xd true hello --par2 "string test" --par23=whatever`

Comment: @NilsBergmann  don't know which programming language are you using. If you are handling arguments, I don't think regex is a best way to go. E.g., your argument value could have `=` and `-`, `--` as well.  There could be Argument Parsers available.  Use them if you find some.

Comment: I don't want to use a parser. And parameters are fine to mach with (-(-)?\w*(=\w*)?) My only problem is to mach anything else. Except the first word.